# Error while running ORB_SLAM2 Library

Tags: opencv, slam

As per requirement mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2), I have installed all the required components like Pangolin, OpenCV etc...Now after building the ORB_SLAM2 library, I am getting the following error...

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/libOpenNI.so', needed by `../lib/libORB_SLAM2.so'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I am unable to resolve the bug..please help with a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can install OpenNI:

`sudo apt-get install libOpenNI-dev`

Comment: Thank you, I had to install both OpenNI and OpenNI2

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libopenni-dev libopenni2-dev
```